# How do I embed a view of comments within a view of nodes using Entity Views Attach (EVA)

Tags: views, entities, nodes

I have one view of nodes. My row style is field. Originally I was trying to create a view that displayed all of the nodes, and all of the comments on those nodes.

I run into trouble using a relationship, because then I get duplicate records for every node. So I'm now trying to make a separate comments view and use [entity views attach](http://drupal.org/project/eva) to attach the comment view as a field to the node.

The problem I am running into is that it seems like there is no way to do this using the fields row style. The only place I can add the comments view is in the displays option. 
how can I display a view of my comments within a view of my nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really practical to intercalate the rows of one view into another view. Instead, what I would do, would be to create a view with node as its base table, include comments via a relationship, and select "distinct" under query settings in the advanced Views settings column.

Comment: Thanks, but select distinct does not appear to give the desired result. There is still a duplicate entry. I should have mention im using D7. Is there something I'm missing

Comment: Are you using comments or node as the base table?

Comment: I'm using node as the base table

Comment: You could also try your node title as a grouping field, and/or using aggregation.